# Magento 2: How to translate calendar Widget

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2.2, calendar, local

I want to display a date of a birth calendar(create account page) as per store local.
Any help appreciate

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem adding `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar` to the layout of required page.

For example in your `customer_account_edit.xml` layout you should add the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I know it's an old question but it's still actual and maybe could be useful for someone else.